# Google Analytics Data API only returns Google Ads campaigns with clicks

Tags: google-analytics-api, impressions

I´m trying to use the Google Analytics Data API to download Google Ads data (impressions, clicks, cost) per campaign for a given week. When I compare the data that I get from the API with the data that I (CSV) export from Google Ads in CSV format, it seems that the **API does not return any campaigns that had no clicks (but some impressions).** I`d like to see all campaigns, even if they had only impressions, but no clicks. How can I achieve this? Please see below the request json of my API call from GA4 Query Explorer, my PHP code and a comparison of the data that I get from the API and the CSV export. Thanks a lot!

GA4 Query Explorer json query:

```
{"dimensions":[{"name":"campaignName"}],"metrics":[{"name":"advertiserAdClicks"},{"name":"advertiserAdCost"},{"name":"advertiserAdImpressions"}],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2023-09-25","endDate":"2023-10-1"}],"keepEmptyRows":true}
```

PHP code for similar query:

```
$client = $this->getClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $this->getGa_propertyID(),
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => $startDate,
            'end_date' => $endDate,
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [
        new Dimension(['name' => 'sessionCampaignName']),
        //new Dimension(['name' => 'year']),
        //new Dimension(['name' => 'isoWeek']),
    ],
    'metrics' => [
        new Metric(['name' => 'advertiserAdImpressions']), 
        new Metric(['name' => 'advertiserAdClicks']), 
        new Metric(['name' => 'advertiserAdCost']), 
        
    ],
    'orderBys' => [
        new OrderBy([
            'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                'dimension_name' => 'sessionCampaignName', 
                'order_type' => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::ALPHANUMERIC
            ]),
            'desc' => false,
        ]),
    ],
    'keepEmptyRows' => true,  
    
]);

return $response;
```

Comparison of data from API and Google Ads CSV export
(please note that the first element in the API list (left) is the first campaign that also has clicks)
[image]